Vertical align and center of container using flex-box
How to fit only one item in the center of the container using flex-box?
I can use the justify-content, but it works for all items.
I need to apply justify-content only in one item, probably using flex-wrap.
But I want both items vertical aligned.
It can be achieved using align-items.
How can I fit one item in the center of the container and vertical align the items?

I can align my text vertically, but I couldn't show my item in the center of the container (horizontally).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border: 2px solid powderblue;padding:130px;background-color:orange;
display:flex;flex-direction:row;
">
    <div style="border:2px solid pink;padding:30px;vertical-align:middle;">
    <
    </div>
    <div style="border:2px solid gray;padding:30px;vertical-align:middle;">
    center
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>


I want this:

